# How to use spring with informix database?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, informix

I wanna use spring technologie with one of my project. I started one project as proof of concept but i couldn't get it work.
Connection with informix gets problem due to unsupported informix in the `org.springframework.batch.supportin.DatabaseType`.

Does any body know any other solution to use any spring technologie with informix?
small working example will be very appreciated.

**Error:**

```
    ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication -Application run failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configurer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.BatchConfigurationException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DatabaseType not found for product name: [Informix Dynamic Server]
Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.BatchConfigurationException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DatabaseType not found for product name: [Informix Dynamic Server]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DatabaseType not found for product name: [Informix Dynamic Server]
```